# Regex to change exactly one word

Tags: javascript, regex

Good morning, I need to make a replace in a string that changes just the words exactly the same as the one I'm going through, not changing words that have something more.

For example: changing cars to oldCars but not changing carsId to oldCarsId.

I did the following test but I am not getting the necessary result:

```
sql = sql.replace (/^cars/g, "oldCars");
```

Comment: Use word boundaries - `/\bcars\b/g`

Comment: Side note : having both an anchor (`^`) and the global flag (`g`) makes no sense since the pattern can only be matched once, at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, your solution worked perfectly, thanks.